# Fine Uploader overwrite a file

Tags: javascript, php, fine-uploader

Hello i'm beginner with fine uploader, i have setup my upload form and my endpoints uploader file and handler uploader file. Now i'am trying to importing the same file 2 time but i can't overwrite a existing file, how to do this?

here my fine uploader config in my uploader page

```js
 var restrictedUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            debug: true,
            element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-validation"),
            template: 'qq-template-validation',
            request: {
                endpoint: "report-upload.php"
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: "report-upload.php"
            },
            chunking: {
                enabled: true,
                concurrent: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                success: {
                    endpoint: "report-upload.php?done"
                }
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },
            retry: {
                enableAuto: true,
                showButton: true
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
                itemLimit: 100,
                sizeLimit: 1151200 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
            }
        });
```

Comment: "but i can't overwrite a existing file", what does it mean? You get an error? the second file is being uploaded with different name? please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Ofir, thanks for your answer! [Fine Uploader 5.16.2] responseText = {"success":false,"uuid":"051f96a6-d15a-4b3d-be95-85cf0115f452","error":"File already exists on the server.","uploadName":"xxxxxxxxx.pdf"}.
The second file is uploaded with the same name yes
By overwriting i mean replace it automatically when i drag and drop the same file 2 times

Comment: It seems that the plugin has no configuration to allow overwrite. So, you'll need to create a function that checks if a file with the same name already exists - and if so, remove it before trying to upload the new file.